# Bind in Promotion/Demotion of changeman package failing

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe, serena

I was trying to promote a COBOL program and the package in changeman. The BIND parameters in the package has QUALIFIER option in it. But while promoting I get the error "INVALID QUALIFIER SUPPLIED'

So I removed the QUALIFIER option from the BIND parameters and added and QUALIFIER in the SELECT query of the COBOL program. And when promoted it was successful. But when trying to demote, I get the same error which I got before i.e. BIND failed due to INVALID QUALIFIER supplied.

The qualifier used is a valid one in the DB2 subsytem I use. Is there any way to find out why the QUALIFIER is reported as invalid. Is it registered anywhere in SYSIBM tables may be ? I tried to query SYSIBM.SYSSCHEMAAUTH, but couldn't find any useful info. Can anyone shed some light on this.

Comment: Look in `sysibm.syspackage` column QUALIFIER  (and compare it to collid, owner, creator etc) for your packagename.

Comment: I checked the SYSPACKAGE table earlier. It had the QUALIFIER which was used in the BIND parameter. But now the QUALIFIER name is CMNS. I think this was because I deleted the QUALIFIER option from BIND parameters of the package (?) Is the new value in the SYSPACAKGE table, the reason QUALIFIER is being reported as INVALID during demotion ? But I wonder why the error message came up when I was trying to promote. At that time QUALIFIER in SYSPACAKGE table was the qualifier for the table, not CMNS

Comment: Talk to your local Change Man Administrator.